# Electronegativity of Potassium (Pauling)

Tags: electronegativity

Just a little question, I was taught that the electronegativity of potassium[K] is 1, but I recently discovered most internet resources say 0.82. [Some even say both](http://www.lenntech.com/periodic-chart-elements/electronegativity.htm). **What is the actual electronegativity of potassium, 0.82 or 1?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends which electronegativity scale you choose to use.  There are a lot of different scales for comparing electronegativities of the elements.  I've included a [list](http://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/36_eneg/electroneg.html) of 11 of them below if you're interested.  In any case here are the electronegativities reported for potassium using 5 different electronegativity scales.  All values are in "Pauling units" so that the numbers can be compared.  The Pauling scale is the most commonly used, so 0.82 would be a reasonable estimate for the electronegativity of potassium.

- Pauling 0.82
- Sanderson 0.45
- Allred Rochow 0.91
- Mulliken-Jaffe 0.73
- Allen 0.734

On the Pauling scale, electronegativities range from around 0.7 to 3.98 (fluorine), so as expected, potassium is at the electropositive end.  None of these scales report a value of 1.

**List of 11 Different Electronegativity Scales**

- Pauling Scale: (1932)  Obtains values by thermochemical methods
- Mulliken Relation: (1934)  Defines a relation that depends upon the
  orbital characteristics of an atom in a molecule. Mulliken
  electronegativity is the numerical average of the ionisation
  potential and electron affinity
- Gordy Scale: (1946)  Defines electronegativity in terms of the
  effective nuclear charge and the covalent radius. (Zeff)e/r
- Walsh Scale: (1951)  Relates electronegativity to stretching force
  constants of the bonds of an atom to a hydrogen atom.
- Huggins Scale: (1953) Alternative to Pauling's thermochemical
  procedure
- Sanderson Scale: (1955)  The ratio of the average electron density of
  an atom to that of a hypothetical "inert" atom having the same number of electrons. This ratio is a measure of the relative compactness of the atom
- Allred-Rochow Scale: (1958)  Defines electronegativity in terms of the effective nuclear charge and covalent radius. Like the Gordy scale but uses (Zeff)e/r2
- Jaffe Scale: (1962)  Uses the electronegativity of orbitals rather
  than atoms to develop group electronegativities for molecular fragments (*e.g.* $\ce{CH3}$ vs $\ce{CF3}$) that take into account the charge of a group, the effects of substituents, and the hybridization of the bonding orbital
- Phillips Scale: (1968)  Defines electronegativity in terms of the
  dielectric properties of atoms in a given valence state
- Martynov & Batsanov Scale: (1980) Obtained by averaging the
  successive ionisation energies of an element's valence electrons
- Allen CE Scale: (1992) Configuration energy (CE), the average
  one-electron valence shell energy of the ground-state free atom, is
  used to quantify metal-covalent-ionic bonding